# How can I run PAW requests as part of my build process

Tags: paw-app

We have a bunch of PAW requests that we run manually as a way to assert our system is working properly.

Is there a way to run those tests via the command line, ideally a docker container with PAW that is able to programmatically  run tests ?

Thanks

Nuno

Answer (score 0):

Paw is a GUI interface for mac, so it is not well suited to do automated tests as part of your CI/CD. There are plenty of resources on how to do CI/CD well online, and they also depend on your application setup/language/etc., but if you like using Paw, you should also know there is a way to export the requests in curl, which you can put in a bash script that can be executed easily as part of your build process.

This wouldn't replace a real automated testing suite, but it's better than nothing!